# How can i count the amount of each grade in each category as a set of marks

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am given a set of Marks

```
midtermMarks = [48.0, 64.25, 71.80, 82.0, 53.45, 59.75, 62.80, 26.5,
55.0, 67.5, 70.25, 52.45, 66.25, 94.0, 65.5, 34.5, 69.25, 52.0]
```

I must find how many A's. B's, and C's there are in this set, assuming A is 100-80 B is 79-70 and C is 69-60

Comment: Use `if-else` in `for` loop.

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to create a dictionary having key **'60-70'**, **'70-80'** and **'80-100'** having each value of 0. And get each marks using **for** loop and check each and every condition using **if** statement and if condition fulfills then add 1 to respective key.

> I have done it for you. Hope it works.

**[CODE]**

```
import pprint     # This module prints dictionary in a pretty way

marks = [48.0, 64.25, 71.80, 82.0, 53.45, 59.75, 62.80, 26.5,
     55.0, 67.5, 70.25, 52.45, 66.25, 94.0, 65.5, 34.5, 69.25, 52.0]

counting = {'Number of A\'s': 0, 'Number of B\'s': 0, 'Number of C\'s': 0}  # Dictionary to count the number in given range

for mark in marks:  # Getting each marks from marks list
    if mark >= 80:  # Checking if mark is more than 80
        counting['Number of A\'s'] += 1  # Adding 1 if there is repetition to dictionary

    elif mark >= 70 and mark < 80:  # Checking if mark is more than and equals to 70 but less than 80
        counting['Number of B\'s'] += 1  # Adding 1 if there is repetition to dictionary

    elif mark >= 60 and mark < 70:  # Checking if mark is more than and equals to 60 but less than 70
        counting['Number of C\'s'] += 1  # Adding 1 if there is repetition to dictionary

pprint.pprint(counting)    # Printing the output
```

**[OUTPUT]**

```
{"Number of A's": 2, "Number of B's": 2, "Number of C's": 6}
```

Comment: How could I then later print out the final values instead of as it actively counts through the values

Comment: Whats the **final** values? Do you want only the values without keys?

Comment: In this example, how many A were in these set of marks or how many B in this set of marks, and that the active count is not printed only the final values, the print I would like is "Number of A's:3" or how ever many, because in my current code it prints out the answer as it count instead of showing the final value

Comment: I have edited my answer as your wish. Hope this is what you have wanted. If this solves your problem then don't forget to accept the answer. Thank you

Comment: I know this must have seemed very simple, but this was very very helpful and you're replies were so fast. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I am glad that I am able to help you. And it really helped you then please accept the answer so that it might again others solving the same problem.